# Reposition jQuery alert

Tags: jquery, position, alert

Wondering how to reposition a jQuery alert in form below. Currently it pops up at the very top of the browser, just under the address bar. It would be nice to have it closer to the center of the screen if at all possible. I am very inexperienced with jQuery so your help would be very much appreciated.

Thank you in advance!
Susan

```
{% if template contains 'product' and product.available %}
<script>
jQuery('form[action^="/cart/add"]').submit(function() {
  var product = {{ product | json }},
    cannotAddThisQuantity = false,
    message = 'So Sorry! You must have gotten the last one!  We do not have any more %t in stock.',
    selectedVariantId = jQuery(this).find('[name="id"]').val(),
    quantityToAdd = parseInt(jQuery(this).find('[name="quantity"]').val(), 10) || 1,
    quantityInCart = 0,
    title = '';
    inventoryLimited = false,
    inventory = 0;      
 for (var i=0; i<product.variants.length; i++) {
   if (product.variants[i].id == selectedVariantId) {
     var variant = product.variants[i];;
     title = product.title;
     if (product.variants.length > 1) title += ' - ' + variant.title; 
     if (variant.inventory_management && variant.inventory_policy == 'deny') {
     inventoryLimited = true;
     inventory = product.variants[i].inventory_quantity;
   }
  }     
 }
 if (inventoryLimited) {
   {% if cart.item_count > 0 %}
   var cart = {{ cart | json }};
   for (var i=0; i<cart.items.length; i++) {
     if (cart.items[i].id == selectedVariantId) {
       quantityInCart = cart.items[i].quantity;
    }     
  }
  {% endif %}
  if ((inventory - quantityInCart) < quantityToAdd) {
    message = message.replace('%q', quantityToAdd).replace('%t', title);
    if (quantityToAdd > 1) message.replace('item', 'items');
    cannotAddThisQuantity = true;
   }
  }
  if (cannotAddThisQuantity) {
    alert(message);
    return false;
  }
  else {
    return true;
}
});    
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using alert(), put the 'message' into a custom div and then you can position that wherever you want

jQuery

```
if (cannotAddThisQuantity) {
  $('.myAlertDiv').html(message).fadeIn();
  return false;
}
```

CSS

```
.myAlertDiv{
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  display: none;
  *etc...*
}
```

Obviously change the CSS to whatever you want . . .

Comment: I will try this right now but wondered if you think I should use px or % for the top & left positioning? Just worried if I use px it will not appear correctly across all browsers. What do you think?

Comment: It all depends where you want the alert to appear. If you put it inside another element (e.g. 'header') and make the 'header' position 'relative' the alert, can be positioned absolutely with px or % and that's cross browser friendly.

Comment: Well, I tried this and it isn't working for me. I just copied and pasted your jQuery but now when I try to submit the form nothing happens. It won't let me go forward and no alert is displayed. ??

Comment: Did you leave to else{ return true; } line intact ?
And add an element with the class of 'myAlertDiv' ?

Comment: I did...I copied and pasted both things, and just added a few lines to the CSS. Now no alert is displayed. I've been trying to figure this out for days, not sure what the problem is.

Comment: So you have:

if (cannotAddThisQuantity) {
    $('.myAlertDiv').html(message).fadeIn();
    return false;
  }
  else {
    return true;
}   ?

Comment: That's right. Exactly as you typed above...copied and pasted it just as shown. Weird right?

Comment: Strange - first, go back to the 'alert' version and make sure that it's still working . . .

Comment: I've done that a few times during this process and it works fabulous. Wacky.

Comment: Go back a step and 'alert' cannotAddTheQuantity and see what the value is for both expected right and expected wrong. It might be the case that we're looking in the wrong place for the error...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand...? There's only one alert given "if (cannotAddThisQuantity), otherwise no alert. Maybe I'm not just not clear what you mean...

Comment: Sorry - what I meant was revert to your original code that is showing the alert when you're expecting it. If this doesn't work then you have a more fundamental problem with your code.

Comment: When I revert back to my original alert, before I posted this question, outside of the position of the alert bothering me, everything works perfectly. When I try to change the position then it stops functioning completely. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Yes, that would be my guess as well. Hmmm...I'm not sure what else to do then because I've been meticulous in checking for errors so it's not an issue with the syntax of the new code so I might just have to live with this...